# Lazy parsing with Stanford CoreNLP to get sentiment only of specific sentences

Tags: java, performance, parsing, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

**I am looking for ways to optimize the performance of my Stanford CoreNLP sentiment pipeline. As a result, a want to get sentiment of sentences but only those which contain specific keywords given as an input.**

I have tried two approaches:

**Approach 1: StanfordCoreNLP pipeline annotating entire text with sentiment**

I have defined a pipeline of annotators: tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment. I have run it on entire article, then looked for keywords in each sentence and, if they were present, run a method returning keyword value. I was not satisfied though that processing takes a couple of seconds.

This is the code:

```
List<String> keywords = ...;
String text = ...;
Map<Integer,Integer> sentenceSentiment = new HashMap<>();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "20");
props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneDelete");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text); // takes 2 seconds!!!!
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (int i=0; i<sentences.size(); i++) {
    CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(i);
    if(sentenceContainsKeywords(sentence,keywords) {
        int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class));
        sentenceSentiment.put(sentence,sentiment);
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: StanfordCoreNLP pipeline annotating entire text with sentences, separate annotators running on sentences of interest**

Because of the weak performance of the first solution, I have defined the second solution. I have defined a pipeline with annotators: tokenize, ssplit. I looked for keywords in each sentence and, if they were present, I have created an annotation only for this sentence and run next annotators on it: ParserAnnotator, BinarizerAnnotator and SentimentAnnotator.

The results were really unsatisfying because of ParserAnnotator. Even if I initialized it with the same properties. Sometimes it took even more time than entire pipeline run on a document in Approach 1.

```
List<String> keywords = ...;
String text = ...;
Map<Integer,Integer> sentenceSentiment = new HashMap<>();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit"); // parsing, sentiment removed
props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "20");
props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneDelete");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// initiation of annotators to be run on sentences
ParserAnnotator parserAnnotator = new ParserAnnotator("pa", props);
BinarizerAnnotator  binarizerAnnotator = new BinarizerAnnotator("ba", props);
SentimentAnnotator sentimentAnnotator = new SentimentAnnotator("sa", props);

Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text); // takes <100 ms
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (int i=0; i<sentences.size(); i++) {
    CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(i);
    if(sentenceContainsKeywords(sentence,keywords) {
        // code required to perform annotation on one sentence
        List<CoreMap> listWithSentence = new ArrayList<CoreMap>();
        listWithSentence.add(sentence);
        Annotation sentenceAnnotation  = new Annotation(listWithSentence);

        parserAnnotator.annotate(sentenceAnnotation); // takes 50 ms up to 2 seconds!!!!
        binarizerAnnotator.annotate(sentenceAnnotation);
        sentimentAnnotator.annotate(sentenceAnnotation);
        sentence = sentenceAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0);

        int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class));
        sentenceSentiment.put(sentence,sentiment);
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. I wonder why parsing in CoreNLP is not "lazy"? (In my example that would mean: performed only when sentiment on a sentence is called). Is it from performance reasons?
2. How come a parser for one sentence can work almost as long as a parser for entire article (my article had 7 sentences)? Is it possible to configure it in a way that it works faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to speed up constituency parsing, the single best improvement is to use the new [shift-reduce constituency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml). It is orders of magnitude faster than the default PCFG parser.

Answers to your later questions:

1. *Why is CoreNLP parsing not lazy?* This is certainly possible, but not something that we've implemented yet in the pipeline. We likely haven't seen many use cases in-house where this is necessary. We will happily accept a contribution of a "lazy annotator wrapper" if you're interested in making one!
2. *How come a parser for one sentence can work almost as long as a parser for an entire article?* The default Stanford PCFG parser is [cubic time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) with respect to the sentence length. This is why we usually recommend restricting the maximum sentence length for performance reasons. The shift-reduce parser, on the other hand, runs in linear time with respect to the sentence length.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon! I may take a look into this lazy parsing. :)

Comment: I have tried out the ShiftReduceParser and indeed the performance of processing is great! Unfortunately, it is too heavy in memory to make use of it with our (already heavy) environment.