# Running the Stanford NLP Pipeline in stages

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the core pipeline in multiple steps to cut down on expensive parsing and annotation steps.

I have a collection of documents, currently I am tokenizing and Sentence breaking them with the pipeline. This is working great and I can do what I need to with this information, up to a point.

Depending on processing I do of the tokenized sentences, some need to dependency parsed, some need NER, some can just be thrown out as unimportant.

I can see that the dependency parsers can take in a CoreMap of a sentence and give me back the dependency graph. But reading online I see that having POS tagging will improve the parsing, which of course makes sense. The NER is also going to need POS most likely?

Sentences that need NER do not need to be dependency parsed, for me.

The POS tagger though does not appear to be able to take in a CoreMap representing a tokenized sentence though.

Is there a way I can run POS tagging and then either NER or dependency parsing on a tokenized sentence from the core pipeline only running tokenize and ssplit?

Comment: From the looks of it I found the answer here in Approach 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714693/lazy-parsing-with-stanford-corenlp-to-get-sentiment-only-of-specific-sentences

Answer (score 0):

I can give two answers to your problem. Within the usual CoreNLP interface, you can set up an annotation pipeline with only certain steps, and another with later steps, and at different points in the code pass the text through each pipeline. For example, the first could have annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos" and the second could have annotator "ner". Once you've passed an `Annotation` through the first pipeline, it can be run through the second:

```
Annotation ann = new Annotation("this is a sentence");
StanfordCoreNLP stage1 = new StanfordCoreNLP(new Properties(){{
  setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos");
}});
stage1.annotate(ann);
// <DO OTHER THINGS>
StanfordCoreNLP stage1 = new StanfordCoreNLP(new Properties(){{
  setProperty("annotators", "ner");
  setProperty("enforceRequirements", "true");
}});
stage2.annotate(ann);
```

I can also shamelessly plug a wrapper for CoreNLP that I've been working on in my spare time: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple. One of the perks is its lazy computation of annotations. So, you could do something like:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.*
Sentence s = new Sentence("this is a sentence");
// Loads the POS tagger, but nothing else
String[] tags = s.posTags();
// <DO OTHER THINGS>
// Now, load the NER tagger
String[] nerTags = s.ners();
```